# Submit second form with first form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, image-uploading

i made a plugin to upload a image file which is already exist in database.image of plugin given below.
[image: my plugin]
This modal have one `<form>` tag.
Now i wants to implement this code to my form.so Form Have Already one form So how can i manage Both Form.

if user upload file than above form will skip and this form is submitted and above data will be lost.
My Form is like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

remember you should provide your work

```
       $("#html_form_id").submit(function() {

            $( "#modelForm_id" ).submit();

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: in modal if user press submit form will automatically submit

Comment: @tarang when model form submitted the form on back is also submitted

Comment: thank you.but you can see my form image in that image is given in center.so user have to input some details after choose image. so have any sollution for this ?

Comment: @tarang  you want if you uploads image through the form below in description, model should not open ?

Comment: @tarang I shared same code if you submit model_form your backend form will submit too at a same time

Comment: no user fill form than chooose image or upload from modal and fill other details and than press submit than all details and image will be update to database.
currently if user choose image and submit from modal than modal form submits and image should upload but details wont.

Answer (score 0):

Description is ambiguous not clear if you want to submit first form, second form or both.

Comment: User First Fill details 
than select image 
Than again fill detail
and when press submit from form 1 All image and Data should be submit.

Comment: use @shashi's answer swap modelForm_id & html_form_id

Comment: @TarangPanchal bro it's too hard due to language to understand what you actually want to do